# When can a sum of exponential decays be approximated by a single exponential decay?

Tags: radiation, half-life

In my experiment, I have a signal y(t) that should be given by a continuous sum of exponential decays:

$y(t) = \int_a^b n_0(E) \exp[-t/\tau(E)] {\rm d}E$

However, I see just a single exponential decay. My ansatz is that what I observe is the following:

$N_0 \exp(-t/\bar{\tau}(E))$
, where $N_0 = \int_a^b n_0(E) \,{\rm d}E$, and $\bar{\tau} = \frac{1}{N_0} \, \int_a^b n_0(E) \, \tau(E)\,{\rm d}E$ (i.e. $\bar{\tau}$ is a weighted average)

That is,
$\int_a^b n_0(E) \exp[-t/\tau(E)] {\rm d}E \approx \left[ \int_a^b n_0(E) \,{\rm d}E \right]\,\exp\left[-t\frac{\int_a^b n_0(E) \,{\rm d}E}{ \, \int_a^b n_0(E) \, \tau(E)\,{\rm d}E} \right]$

Are my intuitions correct? It seems to me that if $\tau(E)$ does not depend on $E$ then it is true. Or also if $b-a \rightarrow 0$ then this is true also.

Any ideas how I can prove this, or at least make my argument more rigorous?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve: prove that you really have the single exponential decay? Than your question lack an example of the data and the description of the fitting procedure.

Comment: I'm trying to ask under what assumptions/limits, can the integral be pushed into the exponent of e.

Comment: I don't think that you need to push the integral into the exponent. Your relaxation time is constant, that's all.

Comment: I've edited the original question to show the approximation I want to use. This approximation (as we've both pointed out) is valid if there's only a single value of $\tau$. But this is the trivial case only.

Comment: Why do you need an approximation? Do you have a model of the relaxation time that is manifestly energy dependent and contradicts your observations? I understand, this is not the direction of your reasoning, but think it over.